# LD_LIBRARY_PATH affects executable path

Tags: linux

I have two versions of python installed on centos 6.4. It came with python 2.6.6. I installed 2.6.2 in /home/python. 
My PATH variable has 2.6.6 in the path(/usr/bin/python). So in the console when I type 'python' it loads 2.6.6.
but, if I change the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to add /home/python/lib and no change to PATH variable, when I type 'python' at the console, it loads 2.6.2.
My understanding of executable search order in linux is 'looks at PATH' to find it. So how come the change in LD_LIBRARY_PATH loads 2.6.2? May be understanding is wrong. Could somebody help me understand this behavior?

Comment: do `ldd $(which python)` in each case, this is probably due to the library versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"python" is a stub executable which loads the Python interpreter from its library. You've told it to look at a different set of libraries first, and so it uses the one it finds there rather than its normal library.